# how to use onClick on react-ripples?

Tags: reactjs, axios

i create component MyButton1 to use react-ripples, but when i use onClick in MyButton1, it's not working

it's working normaly if i use button tag but i want to use my component

my code :

```
export const Register = () => {    
    const postRegister = () => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/user/register', {
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
        })
            .then(() => {
                alert('đăng kí thành công')
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err));
    }

    const register = () => {
        console.log('onClick work')
        postRegister()
    }

    return (
        <div className="login-site">
                <form className='form-login'>
                    <h1 className='login-form-title'>Đăng Kí</h1>
                    <div className="form-row">
                        <input onChange={getEmail} type="email" 
                        name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-row">
                        <input value={username} onChange={getUsername} type="email" 
                        name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tên đăng nhập" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-row">
                        <input value={password} onChange={getPassword} type="password"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-button-right">
                        <a href="#" className="login-form-link">Quên mật khẩu?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-button-center">
                        <div>
                            <MyButton1 onClick={register}>Đăng kí</MyButton1>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" className="login-form-link">Đăng nhập</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

in MyButton1 component code:

```
 export const MyButton1 = (props) => {
    return (
        <Ripples color="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" during={650}>
            <Button className='my-button-1'>{props.children}</Button>
        </Ripples>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `MyButton1` doesn't have an `onClick` props**

Since the onClick handler is only available on the native HTML element, you would need to pass it down to your `Button` component which supposedly also have that handler already.

Something like this:

```
export const MyButton1 = (props) => {
  return (
    <Ripples color="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" during={650}>
      <Button className="my-button-1" onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</Button>
    </Ripples>
  );
};
```